# Is there a way from within windows to identify which BIOS is in the machine?

Tags: windows-7, bios, hardware-detection

I'm wondering if there's a way to retrieve information on the BIOS from within Windows 7 without rebooting and going into the BIOS.

I've checked `Control Panel\System and Security\System` and `Device Manager`.

A registry key or a built-in GUI or commandline tool is fine, I would also settle for something I have to download if there is no included way.

The more info it can get the better. For instance  American Megatrends / Phoenix / Award plus version numbers, dates, whatever.

**UPDATE**

I have now been able to find some settings in the registry...

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\SystemBiosDate`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\SystemBiosVersion`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\VideoBiosDate`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\VideoBiosVersion`

Is there any more detailed information that can also be retrieved from within the OS?

Comment: By "information on the BIOS" do you mean information *about* the BIOS or actual settings within the BIOS?

Comment: @Tarek Fadel: The former, "information *about* the BIOS".

Comment: You can't then.  That's up to the manufacturer to implement (and provide software for).  I've seen some (e.g. ASUS/Gigabyte) do this on their recent motherboards, but there is no use-for-all program.

Comment: @Mazura: I was asking this question 3 and a half years before it was cool (-;

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind a little vbscript, the code below will return everything that Windows knows about the BIOS. I can't take credit for the code - it comes directly from the Microsoft [Scriptomatic](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=12028) app.

Copy the code below into a file called BIOS-Info.vbs (or whatever you want to name it), and then at a command prompt type: `cscript BIOS-info.vbs`

vbscript code follows:

```
On Error Resume Next

Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = &h20

arrComputers = Array(".")
For Each strComputer In arrComputers
   WScript.Echo
   WScript.Echo "=========================================="
   WScript.Echo "Computer: " & strComputer
   WScript.Echo "=========================================="

   Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
   Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS", "WQL", _
                                          wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

   For Each objItem In colItems
      strBiosCharacteristics = Join(objItem.BiosCharacteristics, ",")
         WScript.Echo "BiosCharacteristics: " & strBiosCharacteristics
      strBIOSVersion = Join(objItem.BIOSVersion, ",")
         WScript.Echo "BIOSVersion: " & strBIOSVersion
      WScript.Echo "BuildNumber: " & objItem.BuildNumber
      WScript.Echo "Caption: " & objItem.Caption
      WScript.Echo "CodeSet: " & objItem.CodeSet
      WScript.Echo "CurrentLanguage: " & objItem.CurrentLanguage
      WScript.Echo "Description: " & objItem.Description
      WScript.Echo "IdentificationCode: " & objItem.IdentificationCode
      WScript.Echo "InstallableLanguages: " & objItem.InstallableLanguages
      WScript.Echo "InstallDate: " & WMIDateStringToDate(objItem.InstallDate)
      WScript.Echo "LanguageEdition: " & objItem.LanguageEdition
      strListOfLanguages = Join(objItem.ListOfLanguages, ",")
         WScript.Echo "ListOfLanguages: " & strListOfLanguages
      WScript.Echo "Manufacturer: " & objItem.Manufacturer
      WScript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name
      WScript.Echo "OtherTargetOS: " & objItem.OtherTargetOS
      WScript.Echo "PrimaryBIOS: " & objItem.PrimaryBIOS
      WScript.Echo "ReleaseDate: " & WMIDateStringToDate(objItem.ReleaseDate)
      WScript.Echo "SerialNumber: " & objItem.SerialNumber
      WScript.Echo "SMBIOSBIOSVersion: " & objItem.SMBIOSBIOSVersion
      WScript.Echo "SMBIOSMajorVersion: " & objItem.SMBIOSMajorVersion
      WScript.Echo "SMBIOSMinorVersion: " & objItem.SMBIOSMinorVersion
      WScript.Echo "SMBIOSPresent: " & objItem.SMBIOSPresent
      WScript.Echo "SoftwareElementID: " & objItem.SoftwareElementID
      WScript.Echo "SoftwareElementState: " & objItem.SoftwareElementState
      WScript.Echo "Status: " & objItem.Status
      WScript.Echo "TargetOperatingSystem: " & objItem.TargetOperatingSystem
      WScript.Echo "Version: " & objItem.Version
      WScript.Echo
   Next
Next


Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmDate)
WScript.Echo dtm: 
    WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(dtmDate, 5, 2) & "/" & _
    Mid(dtmDate, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(dtmDate, 4) _
    & " " & Mid (dtmDate, 9, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmDate, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmDate,13, 2))
End Function
```

Comment: I forgot about that, Ive even used that script before.

Answer (score 1):

msinfo32.exe will give you some information about the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Open Microsoft Word,  click the help menu, and then click "About Microsoft Word",  Then click "System Info".  You will find everything there. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah I see it just runs `msinfo32.exe` that Keltari talks about in [his answer](http://superuser.com/questions/322917/is-there-a-way-from-within-windows-to-identify-which-bios-is-in-the-machine/323168#323168).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain but I think that cpuid may do it you can download it from here.

http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html